# Ensure that there are no more than 3 digits before the decimal point error when submitting a form

Tags: python, django, django-models, decimal

I am getting the error "Ensure that there are no more than 3 digits before the decimal point" when I am trying to submit a modal form.

How can I fix it?

my model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    quantity = models.DecimalField( "Quantity", max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    retail_price = models.DecimalField( max_digits=8, decimal_places=4, default=0, blank=True)
    purchase_price= models.DecimalField( max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
    timi_xondrikis = models.DecimalField( max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, default=0, blank=True)
```

my form:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        #fields = '__all__'
        fields=('quantity','retail_price')

        widgets = {
    'retail_price' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max':9999.99})
}
```

**Giving to price field 900 or 900.00 is acceptable but giving 1000 or 1000.00 which I want, is not. The thing is that i define my retail_price field to have max_digits=10.**

[image]

Why this happening?

Comment: Isn't this actually what you want.  It is telling you the number is too big?>

Comment: and 1000 is 4 digits before the decimal point

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to increase `decimal_places`, as per [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DecimalField.decimal_places):

> For example, to store numbers up to 999 with a resolution of 2 decimal
>   places, you’d use:
>
> ```
> models.DecimalField(..., max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
> ```

So use `decimal_places=4` if you want to store 10000.

Comment: I hope you haven't added `'retail_price' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max':999.99})` when testing this code, also try clearing *.pyc files and restart server.

Comment: Finally, it has to do with what you have said concerning max_digits and decimal_places.

Answer (score 0):

Add a widget for your `retail_price` in the form `Meta` which specifies the max value

```
widgets = {
    'retail_price' : forms.NumberInput(attrs={'max':999.99})
}
```

Comment: have you got `from django import forms` ?